# How to import a user module which has the same name with a system module?

Tags: python

I have a legacy python program which defined a module whose name conflict with a system module in the current python, what's the easiest method to fix this? This module has been imported in many place, so it would be great if no need to change the the old python source.

Comment: What's wrong with fixing the old source?   It's easy to do.  What stops you?

Comment: This module is referenced in many places. So it's better if there is some other simple change which could fix this. Anyway, changing the source code could be a fall back solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom import routine using the [`imp module`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/imp.html).  For example, here I'm importing a module named `string` which shadows the real string module:

```
import imp

def user_import(name, path):
    mod_file, mod_path, mod_desc = imp.find_module(name, [path])
    return imp.load_module(name, mod_file, mod_path, mod_desc)

# load the real 'string' module
import string
print string.digits

# load the user 'string' module which lives under the path './foo'
mod = user_import('string', './foo')
print mod.digits
```

Output:

```
0123456789
thesearenotdigits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always rename a module when you import it, such as:

> import sys as realsys
>
> realsys.exit(1)

It seems like you'll have to do this either for the system module whose name you have overloaded or for your module, depending on which causes the least pain.

Bottom line, when you create modules, it's good to more fully qualify the name, e.g. instead of creating `sys` (in this example), you could have created `mylib.sys`.